# TeamCity - Run separate build configurations to compile and deploy

Tags: teamcity

I have two build configurations in a teamcity project - Conf A and Conf B. Conf A is used to compile and build jars while Conf B is used to deploy to a specific environment based on the testing requirements.  I setup Conf B with a dependency on Conf A to share build version information. Now the problem is whenever conf B is run, it first checks if Conf A has any new checkins since the last build and starts running conf A.

What I want is conf B should just pickup the currently available build jars and deploy to the specified environment without checking if there are any new check-ins.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I see & presume @BrokenGlass might have answered your question. Artifact dependency will do the trick of downloading. Other alternative would be to build & _ftp_ required jars/files to _test_ environment for which you have triggered build part & run deployment steps in your deploy build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like instead of a snapshot dependency what you really want is an [**artifact dependency**](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Artifact+Dependencies) from Conf B to the last successful build of Conf A.

You can configure that under the dependencies setting for Conf B, provided you publish your Jars as [artifacts](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Artifact) in Conf A (see links for documentation).

Comment: Thanks for your help, it did solved my problem but got a different problem now. The build package contains thousands of files and its taking significant amount of time in building the artifacts and increased the build completion time by three folds. 

I'm still looking for a suitable solution.